# "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out" when i run gcp bookshelf sample code local

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

When I run the bookshelf sample code of GCP on my local machine with the following:

`mvn -Plocal clean jetty:run-exploded -DprojectID=myprojectid`

the console has an error, and Jetty cannot startup.

The error that occurs is:
`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`

I am using JDK 1.8 with Intellij IDEA.

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Deadline exceeded
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:129)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:114)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:182)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:178)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:174)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:173)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:73)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:167)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:158)
        at com.example.getstarted.util.DatastoreSessionFilter.init(DatastoreSessionFilter.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:725)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.execute(JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.java:69)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: 
com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Deadline exceeded, code=DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:226)
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:193)
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.runQuery(Datastore.java:119)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:180)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:178)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:174)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:173)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:73)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:167)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:158)
        at com.example.getstarted.util.DatastoreSessionFilter.init(DatastoreSessionFilter.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:725)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.execute(JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.java:69)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:183)
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.runQuery(Datastore.java:119)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:180)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:178)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:174)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:173)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:73)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:167)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:158)
        at com.example.getstarted.util.DatastoreSessionFilter.init(DatastoreSessionFilter.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:725)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.execute(JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.java:69)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
2019-02-17 09:46:23.405:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6971f5f4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

Comment: It seems that it is not able to connect to your datastore: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Deadline exceeded, code=DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Comment: thx，but how can i connect？

Comment: Have you started the local server?  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server  It seems like you haven't.

Comment: Could you solve the issue guruboy? In case you did, please put it as an answer.